# Get name of JavaScript Multi-dimensional array, not children

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a JavaScript multi-dimensional array that had multiple values with a ton of sub-values. Here's what I mean:

```
var items = {
    "Area": [
        "Feet",
        "Meters"
    ],
    "Frequency": [
        "Hertz",
        "Kilohertz"
    ]
};
```

I want to cycle through each first dimension item (like Area and Frequency). I do not wanna cycle through sub-values but get the name of the first dimension values.

Here's my code to cycle:

```
$(function() {
    $.each(items, function(index) {
        $(".category").append("<option>" + items[index].text + "</option>");
    });
});
```

Just to be sure, I want to get the names of each first-dimension values, like Area and Frequency. I've tried things like .text, .val, .val() (jQuery), .innerHTML, etc but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: Putting nothing after items[index] just returns the sub-values to each first dimension items.

Comment: You want `Object.keys(items)`

Answer (score 3):

What you have rather than a multi-dimensional array is an object (or map, hashmap, whatever it's called in other languages ;))

To get all the keys you can use `Object.keys(myObj);`

```js
var items = {
    "Area": [
        "Feet",
        "Meters"
    ],
    "Frequency": [
        "Hertz",
        "Kilohertz"
    ]
};

var keys = Object.keys(items);
console.log(keys);

// iterate through them
keys.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(index, item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but Aniket Sahrawat's post helped me and is a lot simpler so I'm gonna stick with his.Thank you anyways and I hope this helps someone else with their issues.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `items[index]`, it means you are referencing to value of `items`. `index` is the key and `items[index]` is the value. Try this code:

```js
var items = {
  "Area": [
    "Feet",
    "Meters"
  ],
  "Frequency": [
    "Hertz",
    "Kilohertz"
  ]
};
$(function() {
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    $(".category").append("<option>" + index + "</option>");
    console.log(index);
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! At first I thought that wouldn't work because usually "index" is the number of the item that is current cycled through, but it worked! I'm gonna use this from now on.

Comment: `index` is the key and not a number

Comment: @JacobGunther also this:- if you are doing `$.each(items, function(index)`, then the word `index` is actually a value. If you want key and values you must do like `$.each(items, function(k, v)` where `k` is the key/index and `v` is value corresponding to the key/index.

Comment: Thanks for that, I kept thinking index was the number that was currently being cycled, but I forgot about value. I'm very used to PHP and that is probably why I got them mixed up.